# Duplicating the second monitor of an extended desktop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have an iPad with duet display, which makes my pc treat the iPad like a second monitor while connected via USB. I also have access to a monitor that connects with VGA, and I would like to know if there is any way to use the iPad only as an extended desktop, while duplicating what is sent to the iPad on the monitor’s screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try Spacedesk https://spacedesk.net/
Driver module on Windows PC (primary) and Viewer Software on iPAD (secondary). 
Devices must be on the same IP-subnet (LAN).

As a result, iPAD will be a regular external Windows display and all operations via Settings/Win-P are possible.